# how to control/sanitise Open Policy Agent (OPA) response

Tags: opa, open-policy-agent

I have the following policy working just fine but its response feels a bit dirty. I am only interested in the `allow` and `permissions` keys.

```
package example 
default allow = false

getUserPermissions(user) = userpermission {
    allowed_list := {"users": {
        "a": {"permissions": [
            "app.write",
            "app.approve",
            "app.read",
        ]},
        "b": {"permissions": [
            "app.write",
            "app.read",
        ]},
    }}
    userpermission = allowed_list.users[user].permissions
}

has_any_privilege(x_arr) {
    uid := input.user
    permissions := getUserPermissions(uid)
    permissions[_] == x_arr[_]
}

default approve = false
approve {
    has_any_privilege({"app.approve"})
}

default write = false
write {
    has_any_privilege({"app.write"})
}

default read = false
read {
    has_any_privilege({"app.read", "app.write", "app.approve"})
}

allow {
    has_any_privilege({"app.read"})
}


permissions := {
    "approve": approve,
    "write": write,
    "read": read,
}
```

when I use the following input:

```json
{"user": "b"}
```

the response is

```json
{
    "allow": true,
    "approve": false,
    "permissions": {
        "approve": false,
        "read": true,
        "write": true
    },
    "read": true,
    "write": true
}
```

the `read`, `write`, `approve` are kind of helper rules I created to be able to build the permissions key correctly.

How can I restrict the response to contain just the `allow` and `permissions` keys?

[Here is the above example in opa playground](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/8Ufgv6o7r8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rego Playground evaluates the entire package, which is why you’re seeing all the rules in the output. When you’re running OPA as a server, you’d normally only query one specific rule for evaluation, e.g /v1/data/example/allow

You can do that in the playground too by selecting the allow rule, which will change the Evaluate button to “Evaluate Selection”.

Comment: is there any thing I can do to get both `allow` and `permissions` in one request without the helper policies? is there kind of local policy/variable definition?

Comment: Create a single rule that includes both, e.g. `response := {"allow": allow, "permissions": permissions}` then query that. Or you could move the helper rules to another package.